# Display MessageBox in View when login verification in ViewModel is successed

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, devexpress

I want to display a message in View based on login value in ViewModel when login button is clicked.

```
//ViewModel
private enum Validate { InvalidForm, Success, AuthorizationFail, ConnectionFailed }
int loginValidation;
public void Islogin()
{
    if (username.Equals(string.Empty) || password.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        loginValidation = 0;
    }
    try
    {
        var user = dxdbEntities.UserViews.Where(x => x.username.Equals(username) && x.password.Equals("password"));
        if(user.Count() > 0)
        {
             loginValidation = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            loginValidation = 2;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        loginValidation = 3;
    }
}

// View
FluentApi.WithEvent(buttonLogin, "Click").EventToCommand(x => x.Islogin());
```

Please give me an example.

Comment: If you are using `ICommand` then you can handle it in your view's code behind.  It doesn't break MVVM though doing the equivalent in your viewmodel even via tricky service injection indirection, _does_ IMHO

Comment: @KimRamin do you have access to Google? do a simple google search

Comment: I try already but rarely resource related with that

Comment: @KimRamin Small suggestion: if you are using the DevExpress button you should not use the event-to-command approach - the best practice is using a command binding either as I have answered in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745491/call-method-in-viewmodel-when-button-in-view-is-clicked-tags-net-winforms) or as follows:
`fluentApi.BindCommand(buttonLogin, x=>x.IsLogin())`

Comment: @MickyD: JFYI, when talking about the DevExpress controls, it is not needed to think about ICommand and any special handling at the View side because of [POCO-Commands](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/113965/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Concepts/Commands#poco) at the ViewModel side and [command-bindings](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117019/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Concepts/Fluent-API-Support) at the View side.

Comment: @DmitryG The presence of `ICommand` in no way demotes a class from being a POCO.   What was unclear to me was what the OP was using.  Hmmm...the way DevExpress does things is interesting.  How does it work with WPF?   Will my XAML button bound to a command on the VM automatically enable/disable.  Also with the fluent stuff, will I see my commands at all from the  XAML designer?  (perhaps a question I should ask on SO proper) :)  Wishing you well

Comment: @MickyD POCO command works practically the same both in WPF and in WinForms - It generates an ICommand property, based on specific Execute/CanExecute methods(this is a conventional mechanism). Thus, yes and yes - all the UI elements bound to the corresponding commands will be updated correctly. Personally, I have preferred the WinForms as a development platform due to the performance reasons, but AFAIK XAML designers for DevExpress controls have the full support of POCO-commands. Moreover, at from the design-time point of view, the POCO stuff have no differences with manually implemented one.

Comment: @MickyD I believe [this root article about the DevExpress MVVM Framework](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/15112/MVVM-Framework) can be interesting for the XAML-developers:-). Personally, I can recommend reviewing at least articles about [POCO](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/17352/MVVM-Framework/ViewModels/POCO-ViewModels), [dxbindings](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/115770/MVVM-Framework/DXBinding) and [MIF](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/118614/MVVM-Framework/MIF).

Comment: @DmitryG Sweet!  That's good to know.  I'll look into it more.  We have DevExpress at work so might look into using it for MVVM either on WF or WPF.  Thanks good sir :)

Answer (score 1):

To show a message box, use [MessageBoxService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114024/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Design-time-Support/Control-based-Services#msg):

```
public IMessageBoxService MessageBoxService => this.GetService<IMessageBoxService>();
public void Islogin()
{
    if (username.Equals(string.Empty) || password.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        loginValidation = 0;
    }
    try
    {
        var user = dxdbEntities.UserViews.Where(x => x.username.Equals(username) && x.password.Equals("password"));
        if (user.Count() > 0)
        {
            loginValidation = 1;
            MessageBoxService?.ShowMessage("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            loginValidation = 2;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        loginValidation = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but we can use IMessageBoxService in ViewModel to show message but I don't want to implement the message in ViewModel but in View instead.

Comment: Would you please clarify why you need to show a message box in your view code? Using services in view models is a common practice.